# Java: How can I queue up asynchronous calls to be executed when a certain condition is met?

Tags: java, rest, asynchronous, completable-future

TL;DR: I want to perform an asynchronous Call to a REST-API. The standard call would give me a CompleteableFuture<Response>, however because the API has a limit on how many calls it allows in a certain amount of time I want to be able to queue up calls to 1. execute them in order and 2. execute them only when I am not exceeding the APIs limits at that current moment, otherwise wait.

Long verson:

I am using Retrofit to perform Rest calls to an API and Retrofit returns a CompleteableFuture<WhateverResponseClassIDeclare> when I call it. However due to limitations of the API I am calling I want to have tight control over when and in what order my calls go out to it. In detail, too many calls in a certain timeframe would cause me to get IP banned. Similarly I want to maintain the order of my calls, even if they won't get executed immediately. The goal is to call a Wrapper of the API that returns a CompleteableFuture just like the original API but performs those in-between steps asynchronously.

I was playing around with BlockingQueues, Functions, Callables, Suppliers and everything inbetween, but I couldn't get it to work yet.

Following there is my currently NON FUNCTIONAL code I created as a Mockup to test the concept.

```java
    import java.util.concurrent.BlockingDeque;
    import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
    import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
    import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingDeque;
    import java.util.function.Function;

    public class Sandbox2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {


        MockApi mockApi = new MockApi();

        CompletableFuture<Integer> result1 = mockApi.requestAThing("Req1");
        CompletableFuture<Integer> result2 = mockApi.requestAThing("Req2");
        CompletableFuture<Integer> result3 = mockApi.requestAThing("Req3");

        System.out.println("Result1: " + result1.get());
        System.out.println("Result2: " + result2.get());
        System.out.println("Result3: " + result3.get());

    }

    public static class MockApi {
        ActualApi actualApi = new ActualApi();

        BlockingDeque<Function<String, CompletableFuture<Integer>>> queueBlockingDeque = new LinkedBlockingDeque();

        public CompletableFuture<Integer> requestAThing(String req1) {

            Function<String, CompletableFuture<Integer>> function = new Function<String, CompletableFuture<Integer>>() {
                @Override
                public CompletableFuture<Integer> apply(String s) {
                    return actualApi.requestHandler(s);
                }
            };


            return CompletableFuture
                    .runAsync(() -> queueBlockingDeque.addLast(function))
                    .thenRun(() -> waitForTheRightMoment(1000))
                    .thenCombine(function)
        }

        private void waitForTheRightMoment(int time) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(time);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static class ActualApi {

        public CompletableFuture<Integer> requestHandler(String request) {
            return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return Integer.parseInt(request.substring(3));
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you not have a ScheduledExecutor that runs every 'n' interval and check the existing running tasks. Get new tasks based on allowed limit and runs them?

Comment: The Guava [RateLimiter](https://guava.dev/releases/19.0/api/docs/index.html?com/google/common/util/concurrent/RateLimiter.html) is a simple solution for limiting call rate.

Answer (score 3):

### Pre JDK 9 (JDK 1.8)

You can make use of `ScheduledExecutor` that accepts items to execute asynchronously on a pre-configured thread pool at a pre-fixed rate / delay.

You can obtain such a service as follows:

```
private final ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
```

Once an instance of `ScheduledExecutorService` is created, you can start submitting items (requests) to be executed as follows:

```
executorService.schedule(
    () -> actualApi.requestHandler(req),
    delay,
    unit
);
```

Meanwhile, using a direct call want lead a `CompletableFuture<Integer>` but instead would lead a `ScheduledFuture<CompletableFuture<Integer>>` on which you will have to block to get the wrapped result.

Instead, you would need to block on your final requests results inside the `ScheduledExecutorService` then wrap your final request result in a **completed `ComppletableFuture`**:

```
public <T> CompletableFuture<T> scheduleCompletableFuture(
        final CompletableFuture<T> command,
        final long delay,
        final TimeUnit unit) {
    final CompletableFuture<T> completableFuture = new CompletableFuture<>();
    this.executorService.schedule(
            (() -> {
                try {
                    return completableFuture.complete(command.get());
                } catch (Throwable t) {
                    return completableFuture.completeExceptionally(t);
                }
            }),
            delay,
            unit
    );
    return completableFuture;
}
```

Here down a review version of your implementation:

```
public class Sandbox2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {


        MockApi mockApi = new MockApi();

        CompletableFuture<Integer> result1 = mockApi.requestAThing("Req1");
        CompletableFuture<Integer> result2 = mockApi.requestAThing("Req2");
        CompletableFuture<Integer> result3 = mockApi.requestAThing("Req3");

        System.out.println("Result1: " + result1.get());
        System.out.println("Result2: " + result2.get());
        System.out.println("Result3: " + result3.get());

    }

    public static class MockApi {

        private final AtomicLong delay = new AtomicLong(0);

        private final ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

        public CompletableFuture<Integer> requestAThing(String req1) {
            return this.scheduleCompletableFuture(new ActualApi().requestHandler(req1), delay.incrementAndGet(), TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        }

        public <T> CompletableFuture<T> scheduleCompletableFuture(
                final CompletableFuture<T> command,
                final long delay,
                final TimeUnit unit) {
            final CompletableFuture<T> completableFuture = new CompletableFuture<>();
            this.executorService.schedule(
                    (() -> {
                        try {
                            return completableFuture.complete(command.get());
                        } catch (Throwable t) {
                            return completableFuture.completeExceptionally(t);
                        }
                    }),
                    delay,
                    unit
            );
            return completableFuture;
        }
    }

    public static class ActualApi {

        public CompletableFuture<Integer> requestHandler(String request) {
            return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return Integer.parseInt(request.substring(3));
            });
        }
    }

}
```

### JDK 9 and onward

If you are using a *JDK 9* version, you may make use of [the supported delayed `Executor`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#delayedExecutor(long,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)):

```
CompletableFuture<String> future = new CompletableFuture<>();
future.completeAsync(() -> {
    try {
        // do something
     } catch(Throwable e) {
        // do something on error
     }
  }, CompletableFuture.delayedExecutor(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
```

Your `MockApi#requestAThing` would then be cleaner and shorter and you are no more in need of a custom `ScheduledExecutor`:

```
public static class MockApi {

    private final AtomicLong delay = new AtomicLong(0);

    public CompletableFuture<Integer> requestAThing(String req1) {
        CompletableFuture<Void> future = new CompletableFuture<>();
        return future.completeAsync(() -> null, CompletableFuture.delayedExecutor(delay.incrementAndGet(), TimeUnit.SECONDS))
                .thenCombineAsync(new ActualApi().requestHandler(req1), (nil, result) -> result);
    }
// ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using [bucket4j](https://github.com/vladimir-bukhtoyarov/bucket4j)

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way to produce my desired behaviour. By limiting my Executor to a single Thread I can queue up calls and they will follow the order I queued them up in.

I will supply the code of my mock classes below for anyone interested:

```java
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class Sandbox2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {


        MockApi mockApi = new MockApi();


        CompletableFuture<Integer> result1 = mockApi.requestAThing("Req1");
        System.out.println("Request1 queued up");
        CompletableFuture<Integer> result2 = mockApi.requestAThing("Req2");
        System.out.println("Request2 queued up");
        CompletableFuture<Integer> result3 = mockApi.requestAThing("Req3");
        System.out.println("Request3 queued up");

        //Some other logic happens here
        Thread.sleep(10000);

        System.out.println("Result1: " + result1.get());
        System.out.println("Result2: " + result2.get());
        System.out.println("Result3: " + result3.get());

        System.exit(0);
    }

    public static class MockApi {
        ActualApi actualApi = new ActualApi();
        private ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        ;


        public CompletableFuture<Integer> requestAThing(String req1) {

            CompletableFuture<Integer> completableFutureCompletableFuture = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
                try {
                    System.out.println("Waiting with " + req1);
                    waitForTheRightMoment(new Random().nextInt(1000) + 1000);
                    System.out.println("Done Waiting with " + req1);
                    return actualApi.requestHandler(req1).get();

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }, executorService);


            return completableFutureCompletableFuture;
        }

        private void waitForTheRightMoment(int time) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(time);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static class ActualApi {

        public CompletableFuture<Integer> requestHandler(String request) {
            return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(new Random().nextInt(1000) + 1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println("Request Handled " + request);
                return Integer.parseInt(request.substring(3));
            });
        }
    }
}
```